# How to call a function of a module by string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a module like this

```
# mymodule.py
def myfun():
   print "hello"
```

being called like this

```
# main.py
import mymodule

def run(funcname):
    mymodule[funcname]()
```

in a directory structured like this

```
./
|
|--mymodule/
   |--__init__.py
   |--mymodule.py
|--main.py
```

When I call the `run` method of `main.py` like this

```
run("myfun")
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Understandably. I wouldve been surprised if this worked. The thing is, I need to be able to call a method of a module by string. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
def run(funcname):
    getattr(mymodule, funcname)()
```

Comment: I get this error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'myfun'
`

Comment: I assume then that "myfun" is not declared in the module. I've tested the above locally and found it to work.

Comment: so iv found that if i import the function like this `import mymodule.mymodule.run` then i can use this approach. but not otherwise

Comment: @dopatraman, i don't think `import mymodule.mymodule.run` works if run is a function in mymodule, i think you need `import mymodule.mymodule as mymodule`

Comment: hm, i figured as much. what i need to do is dynamically import mymodule